# How do you know that $\log(1 - p_i) \le - p_i$?

Tags: inequality

I am looking at this inequality from a book on probability:
$$
\log \mathbf{P}(N) \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \log(1 - p_i)\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (-p_i),
$$
where $p_i \in [0, 1)$. How do you know that $\log(1 - p_i) \le - p_i$?

Comment: Use the series expansion for $e^{-p_{i}}$, noting that powers of $p_{i} \to 0$ when $p_{i} \in [0, 1)$.

Comment: Alternatively, use that (1) the tangent approximation to $\log (1 - p_i)$ at $p_i = 0$ is $T_1(p_i) = -p_i$ and (2) $\log$ is concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on $(-1,1)$, $\;\log(1- x)=-x-\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^3}3-\dotsm$

For $p_i=1$, the left-hand side is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the fact that $$\frac{1}{1-p} \geq 1 \quad \forall p \in [0,1).$$
Then integrate both sides from 0 to p $$\int_0^p \frac{1}{1-s} ds \geq \int_0^p 1 ds$$

Answer (score 1):

> A very useful inequality is 
>   $$\log (1+x) \leq x$$
>   valid for every $x>-1$. Moreover, equality holds if and only if $x=0$.

*Proof*: Put $f(x)=x-\log(1+x)$. For $x>-1$, the derivative is: $f'(x)=x/(x+1)$. Since $f'(x)\leq 0$ for $-1<x\leq 0$, the function $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(-1,0)$, and so $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$ for all $-1<x\leq 0$, with equality if and only if $x=0$.
For $x>0$ the derivative $f'(x)$ is positive, so $f$ increases and $f(x)>f(0)$.

Now if  $x < 1$ it follows that $-1<-x$, and so applying the inequality above:
$$\log (1-x) = \log (1+(-x)) \leq -x$$

with equality only for $x=0$. (Thus there is no need to assume $p_i\geq 0$, but only that $p_i<1$).

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} log(1-x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{-1}{1-x} \leq 0 \quad \forall x \in [0,1)$

This proves that $log(1-x)$ is concave. The concavity implies the curve of the function is under its tangent. The equation of the tangent at $x=0$ is $y=-x$ so we must have:

$log(1-x) \leq -x$